# Power Supply Orientation Affecting Output

Tags: power-supply, power, heat

I am using an NI PS-14 power supply from National Instruments. I just noticed on the [data sheet](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/374228a.pdf) that the orientation can effect the output power and even the life of the product.

[image: Datasheet temperature graphs]

You can see the A1 curve drops for each orientation compared to the standard. Why does this matter? What could the orientation possibly be changing that causes this?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Actually, hot gases rise.

Comment: You might notice that these graphs aren't the *actual* current you will get from the unit. Rather, they're the *maximum* current that the unit is specified for. I'm sure you can still draw 3 amps at 60 degC with the unit mounted upside down - but it will overheat (probably within a few minutes).

Comment: Yep, and the specs say if you do that it could reduce the products shelf life by half!

Answer (score 13):

Industrial DIN-mount power supplies are often passively cooled by convection.  That is, they are designed so that the hot air rises out of the enclosure, drawing cooler air from underneath.  The placement of ventilation holes, internal component orientation, internal baffles, etc, all play into the design.

If you choose a different orientation then it doesn't work so well!

Also, these power supplies will specify minimum clearances around them.  These clearances must be met for the same reason.

This particular power supply's data sheet hides the clearance requirements on page 2-7, in an unfortunately-named "Cooling" section:

> Cooling
>
> The NI PS-14 is convection cooled, and direct cooling is not required. However, you must not cover the ventilation grid (for example, with cable conduits) by more than 30%.
>
> Proper installation clearance for the NI PS-14 is 40 mm on top, 20 mm on the bottom, 5 mm on the left and right side when loaded permanently with full power. If the adjacent device is a heat source, 15 mm clearance is recommended between the NI PS-14 and the adjacent device.

Comment: @Micah You're welcome; glad to help :)

Comment: @bitsmack: Of course, if you're willing to use a fan then it does not matter :)

Answer (score 7):

Look at your four graphs.  Temperature is the common theme /axis.  Also note the the variance is small between A1 and A2 orientations.

It's to do with how effectively the enclosure passively cools itself.  Cooling will occur due to the three standard methods, conduction, convection and radiation.  The exact percentages that these three methods contribute to cooling the PSU is extremely difficult to calculate analytically.  You'd have to do a complex thermal finite state analysis considering air flow as well.  The manufacturer probably instrumented the PSU with a thermometer and determined the temperature profiles empirically.

The main difference is the aspect ratio of the box.  This changes the area presented to the convection currents around it.  That's why the difference is fairly small, just as the difference to your eye is fairly small.

I would suggest the main power regulation occurs towards the OUTPUT end of the enclosure.  That's where the heat is generated.  If it's at the top, convection will start there and stop quickly.  If the OUTPUT end is at the bottom, convection starts at the bottom and creates somewhat of a chimney effect along the outside of the box.  This is more effective at cooling.  Orientation D is a similar effect, but uses the DIN rail as a vertical heat sink, which again is more effective than a horizontal DIN rail for cooling.

Orientation C is the weird one, but I'd suggest that this also forms a chimney effect drawing air in from the horizontal table top.  The wide table top will also serve to extend the heat sink effect via the DIN rail's direct contact.

Comment: I strongly suspect that in their calculations for orientation C they assume an insulating tabletop (for anything other than a metal bench this is a reasonable assumption given a little rounding).  This is presumably included for things like bench-testing of prototype systems.